# Simplify bool function

Tags: c#, algorithm

I wrote this function that returns true/false. My head is stuck on this return algorithm and I can not manage to simplify it. Can you please help me? I know It can be simpler regarding return values and not have to have so much return values, please help me simplify it.

```
private bool CheckSourseLang(string flnfo)
    {
        if (CUR_DOWNLOAD.Equals("ST"))
        {

            if (flnfo.eqauls("English"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < WW_Langs.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (p.Contains(WW_Langs[i]))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Does that ever return false?

Comment: @Sayse: yes, it does.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Where? the else clause would escape before ever reaching the last line

Comment: @Sayse: when there is no `return` from the loop, the `return false` statement is reached. (It would probably be easier to read if there were a `return false` after the loop.)

Comment: @MOehm - Ah of course, very obvious now but the flow is a little bit confusing hence why the question was asked I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private bool CheckSourseLang(string flnfo)
    {
        if (CUR_DOWNLOAD.Equals("ST")) return true;
        return !flnfo.Equals("English") || WW_Langs.Any(t => p.Contains(t));
    }
```

Comment: first line should be `return true;`

Comment: @SaebAmini Note the `!` in `if (!CUR_DOWNLOAD.Equals("ST"))`

Comment: The original code returns `true` when `CUR_DOWNLOAD.Equals("ST")` is `false`, yours returns `false`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's suppose to be simpler in order to reduce the returns.

Comment: @Alex Jolig: be honest, this compact solution requires more effort to be understood. And your current solution is just wrong (first condition wrongly fixed).

Comment: He seems to be trolling.  We've provided what the OP asked, and the concept is rather simple.  It takes more effort to evaluate what the logic does when it takes a whole screen and has multiple nested ifs than when it's condensed.  It may be easier to follow when debugging, but it is not less understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a dotnetfiddle for testing.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/kCDIUy

```
private bool CheckSourseLang(string flnfo)
{
    return  !CUR_DOWNLOAD.Equals("ST") || 
             (!flnfo.Equals("English") || 
             WW_Langs.Any(w => p.Contains(w) ) );
}
```

Comment: Note that if `fInfo` is not `English` then return true.

Comment: @Richard, updated and added a dotnetfiddle for sample testing.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, not really.  All those brackets and `if`s.  The logic is nearly a screen long for something that should be rather simple.

Comment: In the condensed version, you need to think thrice to know when false or true is returned. The "negative" logics does not help. You completely lose the relation between the three clauses and the fact that the tests are narrowing down the false condition.

Answer (score 2):

The only case that returns `false` is when the search in the array `WW_Langs` is attempted and fails. Let us make this explicit:

```
private bool CheckSourceLang(string flnfo)
{
    if (CUR_DOWNLOAD.Equals("ST") && flnfo.Equals("English"))
    {
        // Lookup the language string
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < WW_Langs.Count && !p.Contains(WW_Langs[i]); i++)
        {
        }
        if (i == WW_Langs.Count)
        {
           // Array exhausted, the language string was not found !
           return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or, using more modern constructs:

```
private bool CheckSourceLang(string flnfo)
{
    if (CUR_DOWNLOAD.Equals("ST") && flnfo.Equals("English") &&
       !WW_Langs.Any(Lang => p.Contains(Lang)))
    {
        // Lookup of the language string failed !
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

IMO, this is more readable than `return (complex Boolean expression);` as it clearly shows what the `false` case is.  Would be even better if there was a `None` predicate implementing `!Any`, to avoid a negation.

Comment: Yourr for loop text is somewhat confusing on the first read, which makes it harder to understand, especially since you have an empty {} and then utilize the i variable outside the for loop

Comment: @Bernd Linde: I agree. I moved the `if` statement inside the `for` condition for conciseness, but that was a bad idea (I fixed the declaration typo). And the test on `i` for array exhaustion is indeed not immediately intuitive, but I see no better way. In this respect, the second implementation is clearer, and I would love it with a `None` predicate.

Comment: @Bernd Linde: I don't want a version with a `return true` in the loop body, this spoils the effort to have single exit points per truth value. Instead, there should be a `break` and the test on  `i` still needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
 private bool CheckSourseLang(string flnfo)
        {
            if (!CUR_DOWNLOAD.Equals("ST"))
                return true;
            if (!flnfo.Equals("English"))
                return true;
            for (int i = 0; i < WW_Langs.Count; i++)
            {
                if (p.Contains(WW_Langs[i]))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: No real progress wrt the original code: there are still 4 returns, and extra negations.